# cakePHP3 pass variable from controller to view

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a problem when passing a variable from Controller to view in CakePHP3.

File FincasController.php: I have created a public Method to make a report and be able to pass to a Template I have also created.

```
public function worklist()
{   

    $worklist = TableRegistry::get('Fincas'); 
    $query = $worklist 
        ->find()  
        ->select(['id', 'prov', 'municipio', 'paraje', 'poligono', 'parcela', 'f_ult_poda' , 'f_ult_recog' ]);

    foreach ($query as $worklist) {
          if ( $worklist->f_ult_poda > $worklist->f_ult_recog )
              debug($worklist);  //it works fine
      }  

    $this->set('finca', $this->$query); //I have tried also $this->$worklist

}
```

File Template\Fincas\worklist.ctp :

```
<?php debug($finca);?>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$query` it justa a variable, it's not an attribute of your `FincasControllerõ. Why are you using`$this`?

simply

```
$this->set('finca', $query);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick feedback.